# Java name parse library?

Tags: java, parsing

I'm searching for a library similar in functionality to the Perl [Lingua::EN::NameParse](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-EN-NameParse/lib/Lingua/EN/NameParse.pm) module.
Essentially, I'd like to parse strings like 'Mr. Bob R. Smith' into prefix, first name, last name, and name suffix components.  Google hasn't been much help in finding something like this and I'd prefer not to roll my own if possible.  Anyone know of a OSS Java library that can do this in a sophisticated way?

Answer (score 9):

I just can't believe someone hasn't shared a library for this - well I looked in github and there's a javascript name parser that could be easily translated to java: https://github.com/joshfraser/JavaScript-Name-Parser

I also modified the code in one of the answers to work a little better and have included a test case:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class NameParser {
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";
    private String middleName = "";
    private List<String> middleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> titlesBefore = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> titlesAfter = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String[] prefixes = { "dr", "mr", "ms", "atty", "prof", "miss", "mrs" };
    private String[] suffixes = { "jr", "sr", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v", "vi", "esq", "2nd", "3rd", "jd", "phd",
            "md", "cpa" };

    public NameParser() {
    }

    public NameParser(String name) {
        parse(name);
    }

    private void reset() {
        firstName = lastName = middleName = "";
        middleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        titlesBefore = new ArrayList<String>();
        titlesAfter = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    private boolean isOneOf(String checkStr, String[] titles) {
        for (String title : titles) {
            if (checkStr.toLowerCase().startsWith(title))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void parse(String name) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(name))
            return;
        this.reset();
        String[] words = name.split(" ");
        boolean isFirstName = false;

        for (String word : words) {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(word))
                continue;
            if (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == '.') {
                if (!isFirstName && !this.isOneOf(word, prefixes)) {
                    firstName = word;
                    isFirstName = true;
                } else if (isFirstName) {
                    middleNames.add(word);
                } else {
                    titlesBefore.add(word);
                }
            } else {
                if (word.endsWith(","))
                    word = StringUtils.chop(word);
                if (isFirstName == false) {
                    firstName = word;
                    isFirstName = true;
                } else {
                    middleNames.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        if (middleNames.size() > 0) {
            boolean stop = false;
            List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = middleNames.size() - 1; i >= 0 && !stop; i--) {
                String str = middleNames.get(i);
                if (this.isOneOf(str, suffixes)) {
                    titlesAfter.add(str);
                } else {
                    lastName = str;
                    stop = true;
                }
                toRemove.add(str);
            }
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(lastName) && titlesAfter.size() > 0) {
                lastName = titlesAfter.get(titlesAfter.size() - 1);
                titlesAfter.remove(titlesAfter.size() - 1);
            }
            for (String s : toRemove) {
                middleNames.remove(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.middleName)) {
            for (String name : middleNames) {
                middleName += (name + " ");
            }
            middleName = StringUtils.chop(middleName);
        }
        return middleName;
    }

    public List<String> getTitlesBefore() {
        return titlesBefore;
    }

    public List<String> getTitlesAfter() {
        return titlesAfter;
    }

}
```

Test case:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;

public class NameParserTest {

    private class TestData {
        String name;

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String middleName;

        public TestData(String name, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.middleName = middleName;
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        TestData td[] = { new TestData("Henry \"Hank\" J. Fasthoff IV", "Henry", "\"Hank\" J.", "Fasthoff"),
                new TestData("April A. (Caminez) Bentley", "April", "A. (Caminez)", "Bentley"),
                new TestData("fff lll", "fff", "", "lll"),
                new TestData("fff mmmmm lll", "fff", "mmmmm", "lll"),
                new TestData("fff mmm1      mm2 lll", "fff", "mmm1 mm2", "lll"),
                new TestData("Mr. Dr. Tom Jones", "Tom", "", "Jones"),
                new TestData("Robert P. Bethea Jr.", "Robert", "P.", "Bethea"),
                new TestData("Charles P. Adams, Jr.", "Charles", "P.", "Adams"),
                new TestData("B. Herbert Boatner, Jr.", "B.", "Herbert", "Boatner"),
                new TestData("Bernard H. Booth IV", "Bernard", "H.", "Booth"),
                new TestData("F. Laurens \"Larry\" Brock", "F.", "Laurens \"Larry\"", "Brock"),
                new TestData("Chris A. D'Amour", "Chris", "A.", "D'Amour") };

        NameParser bp = new NameParser();
        for (int i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
            bp.parse(td[i].name);
            Assert.assertEquals(td[i].firstName, bp.getFirstName());
            Assert.assertEquals(td[i].lastName, bp.getLastName());
            Assert.assertEquals(td[i].middleName, bp.getMiddleName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The method isOneOf should be rewritten as:

    private boolean isOneOf(String checkStr, String[] titles) {
        for (String title : titles)
            if (checkStr.equalsIgnoreCase(title))
                return true;
        return false;
    } 

Because currently, it will recognize all names starting with a V as a suffix.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could try the [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk) named entity extraction component? It has build in [jape](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch3.html#x5-950003.28) grammar and gazetteer lists to extract first names, last names etc. among other things. See [this](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitap4.html#x23-492000D) page.

Comment: +1 Can you show me an example of how to parse names using GATE

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons has the HumanNameParser class.

https://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-text/jacoco/org.apache.commons.text.names/HumanNameParser.java.html

```
 Name nextName = parser.parse("James C. ('Jimmy') O'Dell, Jr.")
 String firstName = nextName.getFirstName();
 String nickname = nextName.getNickName();
```

Comment: You can find it on [github](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/names/HumanNameParser.java). The current version is still SNAPSHOT however.

Comment: The `org.apache.commons.test.names` package has been removed from that library.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to do the job nicely, it's a port of a php parser. It looks like it's newer than the most recent answer:

https://github.com/tupilabs/HumanNameParser.java

From the ReadMe:

> Takes human names of arbitrary complexity and various wacky formats like:

```
J. Walter Weatherman
de la Cruz, Ana M.
James C. ('Jimmy') O'Dell, Jr.
Dr. Omar A.
```

and parses out the:

```
leading initial (Like "J." in "J. Walter Weatherman")
first name (or first initial in a name like 'R. Crumb')
nicknames (like "Jimmy" in "James C. ('Jimmy') O'Dell, Jr.")
middle names
last name (including compound ones like "van der Sar' and "Ortega y Gasset"), and
suffix (like 'Jr.', 'III')
salutations (like 'Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Dr')
postnominals (like 'PHD', 'CPA')
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code can help :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NamesConverter {

    private List<String> titlesBefore = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titlesAfter = new ArrayList<>();
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";
    private List<String> middleNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public NamesConverter(String name) {
        String[] words = name.split(" ");
        boolean isTitleAfter = false;
        boolean isFirstName = false;

        int length = words.length;
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == '.') {
                if (isTitleAfter) {
                    titlesAfter.add(word);
                } else {
                    titlesBefore.add(word);
                }
            } else {
                isTitleAfter = true;
                if (isFirstName == false) {
                    firstName = word;
                    isFirstName = true;
                } else {
                    middleNames.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        if (middleNames.size() > 0) {
            lastName = middleNames.get(middleNames.size() - 1);
            middleNames.remove(lastName);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getTitlesBefore() {
        return titlesBefore;
    }

    public List<String> getTitlesAfter() {
        return titlesAfter;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public List<String> getMiddleNames() {
        return middleNames;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String text = "Titles before :" + titlesBefore.toString() + "\n"
                + "First name :" + firstName + "\n"
                + "Middle names :" + middleNames.toString() + "\n"
                + "Last name :" + lastName + "\n"
                + "Titles after :" + titlesAfter.toString() + "\n";

        return text;
    }
}
```

---

For example this input :

```
    NamesConverter ns = new NamesConverter("Mr. Dr. Tom Jones");
    NamesConverter ns1 = new NamesConverter("Ing. Tom Ridley Bridley Furthly Murthly Jones CsC.");
    System.out.println(ns);
    System.out.println(ns1);
```

Has this output :

```
Titles before :[Mr., Dr.]
First name :Tom
Middle names :[]
Last name :Jones
Titles after :[]

Titles before :[Ing.]
First name :Tom
Middle names :[Ridley, Bridley, Furthly, Murthly]
Last name :Jones
Titles after :[CsC.]
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would opt for [regular expressions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html). Here's a good [intro](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html). They're fast, concise and *always* do what you want.

If you want to stay within the boundaries of the java sdk, use [String tokenizers](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

A bit more low-level is [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/), a java based parser generator. Here's a [link to a tutorial](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/).

An alternative to javaCC is [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org), which I've personally had good experiences with.