# Java library or algorithm to extract person information from String

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, split

I am looking for a Java library or algorithm to extract person information from a String.
How I can extract person attributes from a String?

Example:

```
String s = "Mr. Dr. Tom Jones";

Person person = new Person(s); 
p.getSurename(); // Jones
p.getFirstname(); // Tom 
p.getSalutation(); // Mr. 
p.getTitle(); // Dr.
```

I am looking for a library based on algorithms via Fuzzy, Levenshtein or Phonetik. I have lists with titles, names and salutations to compare.

I believe there isn't a perfect way. Sure there are many exceptions about name-conventions (some middle names, Jr. abbreviation, ...).  Maybe someone has taken the step?

Comment: Regular expressions should do the job. I suppose there is no "easy" way how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330103/java-name-parse-library

Comment: The best way is to get the user to separate these fields at the point of entry. Once its all been combined you lose that information and can only take a best guess which may not be good enough.

Comment: `Person [surname=Jones, firstname=Tom, salutation=Dr., title=Mr.]` In your approach using String Tokenizer is the one which you can use and get something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this enough?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NamesConverter {

    private List<String> titlesBefore = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titlesAfter = new ArrayList<>();
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";
    private List<String> middleNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public NamesConverter(String name) {
        String[] words = name.split(" ");
        boolean isTitleAfter = false;
        boolean isFirstName = false;

        int length = words.length;
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == '.') {
                if (isTitleAfter) {
                    titlesAfter.add(word);
                } else {
                    titlesBefore.add(word);
                }
            } else {
                isTitleAfter = true;
                if (isFirstName == false) {
                    firstName = word;
                    isFirstName = true;
                } else {
                    middleNames.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        if (middleNames.size() > 0) {
            lastName = middleNames.get(middleNames.size() - 1);
            middleNames.remove(lastName);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getTitlesBefore() {
        return titlesBefore;
    }

    public List<String> getTitlesAfter() {
        return titlesAfter;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public List<String> getMiddleNames() {
        return middleNames;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String text = "Titles before :" + titlesBefore.toString() + "\n"
                + "First name :" + firstName + "\n"
                + "Middle names :" + middleNames.toString() + "\n"
                + "Last name :" + lastName + "\n"
                + "Titles after :" + titlesAfter.toString() + "\n";

        return text;
    }
}
```

---

For example this input :

```
    NamesConverter ns = new NamesConverter("Mr. Dr. Tom Jones");
    NamesConverter ns1 = new NamesConverter("Ing. Tom Ridley Bridley Furthly Murthly Jones CsC.");
    System.out.println(ns);
    System.out.println(ns1);
```

Has this output :

```
Titles before :[Mr., Dr.]
First name :Tom
Middle names :[]
Last name :Jones
Titles after :[]

Titles before :[Ing.]
First name :Tom
Middle names :[Ridley, Bridley, Furthly, Murthly]
Last name :Jones
Titles after :[CsC.]
```

Comment: Would that work for last names consisting of two words, like mine :-)